# Change behavior of bash script if executed from another script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, executable, interactive

I have a script (say `Task.sh`) (with executable permission):

Pseducode:

```
if [[ Not called from inside a script ]]; then
  echo 'Not called from inside a script'
else
  echo 'Called from a script'
fi
```

---

I have a script say `Main.sh` (with executable permission):

```bash
Value=$(Task.sh)
echo "${Value}"
```

---

## Expected Outcome

```bash
$ Task.sh
Not called from inside a script

$ Main.sh
Called from a script
```

## Help Request

Please suggest what conditional to put in the pseducode for `Task.sh`

Comment: Does running `bash -c Task.sh` count as running inside a script? If not, why not?

Comment: Do you want to catch just something like `Value=$(Task.sh)`, or also a script that just runs `Task.sh`? Also, is there some particular reason for `Task.sh` to behave differently in these situations? Knowing the background might help in finding a suitable solution.

Comment: @ilkkachu The Task.sh copies to clipboard if it's not called from inside the script else it just prints it.

Comment: You could investigate your parent process, (and, if you like, its parent, ...). Start with the `$PPID` environment variable. Do: `ps -fp$PPID`. Or look at `sudo ls -l /proc/$PPID`. Read `man proc ps bash`.

Comment: Why not just import the script as a function into the main.sh? Another way to do it is to have both script source different variables. Have main.sh override the variables from task.sh. This way you would know if the script was run by anther script or not.

Comment: @waltinator, I wonder how easy that'd be, the parent could be Bash regardless of if it's a script or an interactive Bash... (What if it's run from a non-Bash script?)

Comment: Apart from just checking if the output is a terminal, a straightforward solution would be to just look at a command-line argument to decide if to use the clipboard or to print something. I would likely make the default action printing, and then the user could use an alias to turn `Task.sh` into `Task.sh --clipboard`, or so. But you could do it the other way around too, since at least the argument needs to be added to the script only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to change the requirements slightly from "*am I running in a script?*" to "*am I connected to a terminal or a pipe/file?*". This would allow for the case of `Task.sh >/tmp/file`: it's not called from a script, but it seems it should write to the file rather than the clipboard.

If that's acceptable then you can use a simple test for *stdout* connected to a terminal:

```
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    echo "stdout is a terminal (tty)"
else
    echo "not a terminal (tty)"
fi
```

Tools like `ls` and `tty` operate differently depending on their usage situation using a very similar approach. For example, in a directory with several entries contrast `ls` and `ls | cat`

Answer (score 1):

Having a tool copy something to clipboard seems rare enough that it might be better to be explicit about it and only do it when asked.

So one option is to the script check for a command line argument asking to use the clipboard, and otherwise default to printing to stdout.

If you don't use command line arguments in the script otherwise, it's as easy as:

```
if [ "$1" = --clipboard ]; then
    copy_to_clipboard "$data" # or whatever
else
    printf "%s\n" "$data"     # print to stdout
fi
```

or include it in your `getopt`(s) loop if you are using command line arguments.

That means an interactive user will need to remember to add the option, but they can just install an alias in their `.bashrc` or equivalent to do that:

```
alias Task.sh="Task.sh --clipboard"
```